# KroneckerDelta does not automatically simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebra

```
R[a_, b_] := FullSimplify[ KroneckerDelta[a, b] KroneckerDelta[a, b]]
R[a, b]
(* KroneckerDelta[a, b]^2 *)
```

Should the the full simplified answer not be just `KroneckerDelta[a, b]` due to idempotence?

Comment: Failure to simplify isn't a bug - so I'd suggest changing the title of the question.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html)

```
R[a_, b_] := KroneckerDelta[a, b] KroneckerDelta[a, b] // PiecewiseExpand

R[a, b]
```

[image]

```
R[a_, b_] := Product[KroneckerDelta[a, b] , {n, 5}] // PiecewiseExpand

R[a, b]
```

[image]

```
R[a_, b_] := 
 Product[KroneckerDelta[a, b] , {n, m}] // PiecewiseExpand[#, m > 1] &

R[a, b]
```

[image]